# Maximum cookies size or cookies character length

Tags: asp.net, cookies, size, local-storage, storage

I am developing an web application in asp.net. Its an online shopping portal in which lots of products are there so when i added any product in cart then its product code with quantity store in cookies like this

```
ED007=1&ED008=1
```

where ED007and ED008 are the product code and 1 is the quantity of each product.

**Problem** : When 180 products are added in cart then cookies is too long, size of 1444 (shows in browser resources) when i try to read the cookies it does not response. My site goes down or probably some problem occur.

So i want the another alternative to store that much amount of data easily.

Answer (score 0):

Some online shopping cart store information in **Database** mapping **CartId** from **Cookie**.

Once check-out is successful, move items to Order and OrderItem tables and clear the cart.

If you do not want that approach, you can also store in **Session State**. Draw-back of using Session State is, if customer closes the browser accidentally, s/he will have to start all over again.